# Javascript validate list of email addresses comma separated

Tags: javascript, list, validation, email

I am using ServiceNow and I need to validate a textbox that will accept a list of email addresses that are separated by commas.

The list of email addresses is in the variable `group_members`.

The validation works for the *first* email address only. The second email address in the list is showing as invalid even though I have tested with a list of valid addresses. For example:

`Testa@example.com, testb@example.com`

`testa` will show up as valid but `testb` will be invalid. I know it is not the regex because the same email address will return valid as long as it is the *first* in the list. I think there is something wrong with looping over the array or perhaps the way that the comma separated list is being split to the array.
Can you check my logic here to see what is wrong?

```
var group_members = g_form.getValue('u_group_members');
var member_split = group_members.split(',');

for (var n = 0; n < member_split.length; n++) {
  var member_info = member_split[n];
  var validRegExp = /^\w+((-\w+)|(\.\w+))*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;

    if (member_info.search(validRegExp) == -1) {
        g_form.showFieldMsg('u_group_members', "Group Members contains an invalid email address. " , 'error');
    }
    else if (member_info.search(validRegExp) == 0) {
        g_form.showFieldMsg('u_group_members', "Group Members email addresses are valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have a space after the comma. Either remove it or account for it in your regex.

```js
var group_members = "testa@example.com, textb@example.com";

document.getElementById('space').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = "";
  run();
});

document.getElementById('trim').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = "";
  run(true);
});

function run(trim) {
  var member_split = group_members.split(',');

  var valid = true;
  for (var n = 0; n < member_split.length; n++) {
    var member_info = trim ? member_split[n].trim() : member_split[n];
    var validRegExp = /^\w+((-\w+)|(\.\w+))*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;

    if (member_info.search(validRegExp) === -1) {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
  }
  if (valid)
    document.getElementById("el").innerHTML += "Group Members email addresses are valid.<br/>";
  else
    document.getElementById("el").innerHTML += "Group Members contains an invalid email address.<br/>";
}
```

```html
<button id="space">Space</button><button id="trim">Trim it</button>
<div id="el"><div>
```

Comment: Or run `member_info=member_info.trim()` before the testing to remove unnecessary whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: This is great thanks. In my implementation I created `var = emailNo = n + 1;` after `valid = false` and then included it in `.innerHTML` like `'Email #'+emailNo+' contains an error'`. That way if it's a long list the user can zero in on the email that has a typo.